# Second window to keep focus on a warning message

Tags: python

I have a main window with lots of widgets etc, and one button opens another secondary  Toplevel() window, which some conversion utilities; I raise a warning_message if data is absent in certain Entry widgets, but when this warning opens, the secondary window goes behind the main (root) window, with the warning over the top of the main (root) window. Once the warning is acknowledged by clicking, the secondary window comes back.
So, how do I keep the secondary window in front of the main window, and the warning in front of the secondary window.
Everything else seems to work OK, but it doesn't make sense to me for the warning to hide the window that called it up?

This is how I open the secondary window, which has a couple of frames each with Entry widgets and Buttons etc:-

```
def Open_Utils():
    util_window = Toplevel(root)
    util_window.title('Conversion Utility')
    util_window.geometry('800x500+150+150')
    util_window.grab_set()
```